# How does STM32CubeIDE locate the header file in such case?

Tags: c, header, stm32cubeide

I created a C/C++ project in STM32CubeIDE as follows:

[image]

In the main.c I had to write the include as follows:

```
#include "..\Inc\myRandom.h"
```

otherwise if I only write #include "myRandom.h", then I get the following error:

```
error: myRandom.h: No such file or directory
```

But if the project were created as a STM32 project for an embedded device the above problem does not exist. For instance:

[image]

Above in main.c **#include "myRandom.h"** did not give any error.

How come I don't need to write **#include "..\Inc\myRandom.h"** in this case?

Comment: All subdirectories in Eclipse bloatware has to be added manually (and this is always buggy). You need to see the `-I` arguments that Eclipse passes to gcc or you can't trust it to do anything correctly. I strongly recommend to use a different IDE.

Comment: What IDE do you like to use? I use this because its easy to transition from CubeMX. But I would like to try others.

Comment: I use Crossworks for all Cortex M projects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you check `Project Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Tool Settings -> MCU GCC Compiler -> Include Paths`, you can find every path that the IDE includes.

If your path does not exist there, you can simply add it.

Comment: This is the way to fix this. Basically, you (OP) will tell the compiler to look specifically in that folder (among others), so any file in that folder can be included without path, only by name, exactly like in STM32 project (A little noob-friendly explanation of your answer - been there myself)

Comment: Although if your name is Klas-Kenny or anything non-English, please check out this Eclipse mistake: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27905796/584518. That was posted 7 years ago, but as far as I know, Eclipse remains broken.

Answer (score 2):

Because when you created the project yourself you didn't add the include path to the compiler settings, while when CubeMX auto-generated the project it didn't 'forget' to add that include path.

So in your project you have to tell the compiler's pro-processor "go up one step in the directory tree (..), then look for a directory called "Inc", and on there you'll find "myRandom.h".
Whereas in the auto-generated project the compiler has already been told that it might be able to find include files in that directory, so it knows to look there automatically.

Note that if you were compiling a .c source file which was not in 'Src', but was instead in the parent directory 'Core', then in your version of the project you'd need to `#include "Inc\myRandom.h"`, leaving out the "..".